# On morphisms of $\mathcal {O}_X $ modules

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

We know that a morphism $\phi$ between two presheaves $\mathcal {F}$ and $\mathcal {G}$ on a topological space $X$ is the data of maps $$\phi(U):\mathcal {F}(U) \to \mathcal {G}(U)$$ $\forall \ U$ open in $X$ such that the following diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
        \mathcal {F}(V) @>\phi(V)>> \mathcal {G}(V)\\
        @V Res_{V,U} V V @VV res_{V,U} V\\
        \mathcal {F}(U) @>\phi(U)>> \mathcal {G}(U)
\end{CD}
commutes for every inclusion $U \subset V$ in $X$.
Now , if $\mathcal {F}$   and  $\mathcal {G}$ are $\mathcal O_X$ modules (where $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ is a ringed space) then morphisms between them are essentially the data of abelian group morphisms $$\phi(U):\mathcal {F}(U) \to \mathcal {G}(U)$$ $\forall \ U$ open in $X$ such that for them ,the above diagrams commute for each inclusion.
Now everywhere it is written that this morphism is same as the data of maps$$\phi(U):\mathcal {F}(U) \to \mathcal {G}(U)$$ $\forall \ U$ open in $X$ which are $\mathcal O_X(U)$ module morphisms. But I have tried a number of times to prove that the property of being abelian group homomorphism together with the compatibility of restriction maps (which we get by virtue of $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ being $\mathcal O_X$ modules) implies that $\phi(U)$'s are $\mathcal O_X$ module morphisms and conversely if we have a bunch of $\mathcal O_X$ module morphisms from $\mathcal F(U)$ to $\mathcal G(U)$ ,then automatically the aforesaid diagram will commute giving rise to morphism from $\mathcal F$ to $\mathcal G$, and I have failed to see the reason why it should be so.The main difficulty is taking $a\in \mathcal O_X(U)$ out of the expression $\phi(U)(a.f)$ for any $f\in \mathcal F(U)$(I have mainly used compatibility condition to show that those abelian group morphisms are indeed appropriate module morphism). I hope once this part is clear, the converse will be easier to see.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Can you please format your question a little more clearly, this feels like rambling.

Comment: @KyleBroder my question is how those abelian group homomorphisms are becoming approprate module morphisms if they satisfy the diagram mentioned in the question.I think I have already mentioned this in the question alongwith mentioning exactly where i am facing problems in showing that they are module morphisms.I have also mentioned that in proving this I tried to use compatibility condition which did not work.

Comment: @HARRY I agree with Kyle. Try modelling the question as:
$$$$
**Question:** Blah blah blah
$$$$
and then follow with your thoughts, etc. If you use `>` it'll highlight a block.

Comment: Is it possible to give the reference where you have found this definition? Because I'm not sure about the part "everywhere it is written...". Surely Hartshorne didn't defined it in this way, there it was explicitly mentioned $\mathcal{F}(U) \longrightarrow \mathcal{G}(U)$ is an $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-module homomorphism (similarly Red Book, and Gortz's Book). Also the thing you are saying is not correct. One can check easily using the equivalence between quasi-coherent sheaves and modules over affine schemes. (Not every group homomorphism can be extended to a module homomorphism).

Comment: @Krish my source is "Foundation of Algebraic geometry" by Ravi vakil.There in page 79(and before) all this definitions are explicitly mentioned .He then asked to find out what should be a morphism between  two $\mathcal O_X$ modules if we follow his definition of morphisms of sheaves and definition of a  $\mathcal O_X$ module(same book page-78) .

Comment: @Krish Also this group homomorphisms are not just any group homomorphisms. They are abelian group homomorphisms which satisfy the diagram mentioned in the question

Comment: I can't find in Vakil's book a quote which can make you think that morphisms of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules are just morphisms of abelian sheaves. I only read "morphisms of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules have the obvious
definition. (Can you write it down?)". Of course, for $\phi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow\mathcal{G}$, you need that the $\phi(U)$ are morphisms of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-modules.

Comment: @Roland $\mathcal F(U)$ and $\mathcal G(U)$ are objects of category of abelian group so naturally we will think of maps  $\Phi(U)$ as abelian group morphism and then we want more (i.e. it behaves well with respect to inclusion). However,If you define that the morphism between these two sheaves are data of all appropriate module morphisms from $\mathcal F(U)$ to $\mathcal G(U)$ (without  diagram condition),then also to say that this new definition matches with our earlier definition of morphisms of abstract sheaves we need to check that all those  morphisms also satisfy the diagram condition.

Comment: And to check that those module morphism satisfy diagram condition ,I think the problem where I got stuck is precisely same problem with my earlier approach.

Comment: No of course you still need the commutative diagram condition. You need both : that $\mathcal{F}(U)\rightarrow\mathcal{G}(U)$ is a morphism of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$-modules AND the compatibility with the restriction. What I am claiming is that you can't skip any of these conditions. None of them implies the other.

Comment: @Roland This definition you are giving makes sense(Instead of module morphism and  diagram condition, I was starting with lesser conditions namely abelian group morphisms and diagram condition and was trying to arrive at your definition but now I think (realize) that the author might not mean us to start with abelian group morphism and diagram condition)